# Thread Dead lock occurs when using Java Observer

Tags: java, multithreading, jakarta-ee, thread-safety, deadlock

In server side, I created  One Non stopping thread ( infinite while loop using in run method) that name as Event extractor and it  extends java Observable .

when i call notifyObservers method it works fine. but at some point the thread has been dead locked.

Does any one help me out to resolve this problem. I have shared the codes below

```
public class EventExtractor extends Observable implements Runnable {

@Override
    public void run() {

          while (true) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(NOTIFY_DELAY); // 60000 milliseconds
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Logs.error("InterruptedException in run() in Extractor",e);
            }
                                    Set<String> productSet= getProductSet();
                        this.setChanged();
            /* notify the products to observer */
            this.notifyObservers(productSet);
            /* clear the set to maintain the products again for a minute */
            Set<String> productSets= getProductSet();
            if (productsSets != null) {
                productsSet.clear();
            }
        }
    }


}


public class FMListener implements Observer{

public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    Set<String> set = (Set<String>) arg1;

    for (String ProductID: set) {
        LOGS.debug("***** obj is:::: " + ProductID);
       //call Http request calls to particular product and update into data base
         httpClient.sendRequest(***URL**);

    }


}
```

getProductSet() is a static method to add products when receive event from the product

Comment: What does getList() do? what are 'devices' and why do you notify with devices and not with products as the comment suggests?

Comment: Hi Eyal I have changed the code. actually i am receiving events from products by listener and i stored the value in static set variable. and i passed into observers for every minute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What makes you think it is a "Dead Lock".  Have you try to do thread dump when you think it is in "dead lock" and found the main thread waiting for something?

The reason I doubt it is actually a dead lock is, there is no obvious locking happening, AND, most importantly, Java's Observer logic doesn't spawn any new thread: the logic of observers are simply running within your caller thread context, which means, there is NO other thread in your situation, hence, just by the logic above, there is no reason to have dead lock

It may be the HTTP Client you are using is not thread-safe and there is someone else using it.  However I think it is more likely to be some uncaught exception (maybe from your observer logic) makes your EventExtractor thread die.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for your valuable answer. I think it might happened due to uncaught exception